# On click instead of going to the link/page, open the page inside a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here I have a  link

```
 <h2 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id;?>">  post  </a>  </h2>
```

when the link is clicked it goes to `post.php?id=1`

How can I prevent going to this link  but at a same time  open this  inside
the div below ?

Note: Anything is put inside the div will automatically show cause it is a modal div.

All I need is to  include the post.php inside the div with id and prevent from going going to the `post.php?id=1`

```
 <h2 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id;?>">  post  </a>  </h2>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

    <div>     




          //include post.php inside here with id




    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the post.php: `

```
<?php 

include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_GET['id'])){

$get_id = $_GET['id'];

$get_query = "select * from posts where post_id='$get_id'";

$run_query = mysql_query($get_query); 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){


    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];

    $post_image = $row['post_image'];

}
}
?>`
<div>

 <h2> <?php echo $post_title;?> </h2>  


</div>
```

Comment: <h2 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">See post</h2>

Comment: You should use client side code like JQuery 'Ajax' ....

Comment: that will just open the modal i need the post.php inside it@DincaAdrian

Comment: @AmanKumar  I would be glad if you show me how to do it

Comment: The content of the post should be included inside the modal isn't it?

Comment: @DincaAdrian yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h2 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">See post</h2>` and then include the post.php into the modal. there is no point of putting the link into the modal opener. since the binding with the modal is made by data-target and not by some link. To improve even better you can use the id from post to generate unique ids in page. in case you want to have multiple posts/modals with something like

```
data-target="#myModal_<?php echo $post_id;?>"
```

and the modal div should have the same. `id="myModal_<?php echo $post_id;?>"`

Comment: I would apreciate a comment of why you downvote it. Thanks

Comment: it worked . thanks for your help man .  anyways I dont know whoever downvoted it but that person should explain why cause i myself  found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h2 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <a href="#" id="post">  post  </a>  </h2>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="include">     

            //include post.php inside here with id

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#post").click(function() {
            var id = "<?php echo $post_id;?>";
            $.ajax({
                url : 'post.php' ,
                method : 'get',
                success : function (res)
                {
                    $("#include").html(res);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

> In Post.php page . You have to take all html into a variable and echo
>   it 
>   note :- your url :- `'post.php'?id='+ id`

**post.php**

```
<?php 
$html = "<h1>This is Post page content</h1>";
echo $html ;
?>
```

Comment: I have added post.php . do i need to change anything inside post.php ??

Comment: you have include jquery cdn in header <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks Aman for your time.But Dinca's one is the exact what I needed

Comment: Welcome@True speaker... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to run some javascript/JQuery.

First off you need to stop the link from activating, as simple `onclick="return false"` should do the trick there. Then you need to tie that click into an `ajax` request to the `post.php`.

Look at building a function to run on click, or an even handler for JQuery:

- [On click](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)
- [Event handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [AJAX via Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)